# $P( X \geq x_1 \cap X \geq x_2)$ when $X$ follows a Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

How would I calculate $P( X \geq x_1 \cap X \geq x_2)$ where $x_1 > x_2$ and $x_1,x_2$ are events and
where $P(X = x) = \frac{e^{−\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}$?

I originally taught the answer would just be $P( X \geq x_1 \cap X \geq x_2) = P( X \geq x_1 )$ but I was reading about the memorylessness property of exponential distributions recently and I'm not sure if it applies to Poissson distributions also.

Comment: $x_1, x_2$ cannot be *events*, which are sets of outcomes.  These cannot be compared to a random variable.  Please clarify: are they constant values or random variables?

Comment: Please learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, I assume you meant $\lambda^x$, not $\lambda x$.

Comment: Sorry, they're random variables.

Comment: Okay, what family of random variables?  What is their distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, if $x_1,x_2$ are constants, then: $\quad \mathsf P(X\geq x_1\cap X\geq x_2)\\ = \mathsf P(X\geq \min\{x_1,x_2\})\\ = 1-\dfrac{\Gamma(\lfloor\min\{x_1,x_2\}+1\rfloor,\lambda)}{\lfloor\min\{x_1,x_2\}\rfloor!}$

---

$\Gamma(x,y)$ is the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken X is a random variable.